# The argument type 'MapEntry<_, _> Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  Map name = {"name": "islam", "age": 34, "price" :34};
void xname = name.map((e) => {
  if (e =="islam"){
    return "zoz";
  }
});
print (xname);
}
```

show me error message: The argument type 'MapEntry<_, _> Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>Function(dynamic, dynamic)

Comment: 1. map method is used to iterate through a list and you are trying to use it with a Map.
2. and you're assigning whatever the value map function is returning to a void function. 
3. If you need to print a value from a map, simply type the map name followed by key name in square brackets: print( name["name"] );

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to substitute map value on some condition, try this

```
final name = {"name": "islam", "age": 34, "price" :34};
final xname = name.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, key == "islam"? "zoz" : value));
print(xname);
```

if `xname` is not a function, don't use `void` keyword. then you are iterating over the map with MapEntry (key, value) and check your condition. and you should return MapEntry on every step.